# absolute positioned div appearing above everything else

Tags: html, css, position, absolute

I wanted a partial purple background that is positioned absolutely behind everything else. When I tried to make this, the div appeared on top of all of my other elements. Is there a way I can make that div appear behind everything instead? I tried using z-index to no avail and looked up some other posts, nothing seemed to work.

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

#topColor {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #9546c1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0;
  z-index=-1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="headerWrapper">
    <h1><img class="centeredImage" src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="Logo"></h1>
  </div>
  <div id="navWrapper"> </div>
  <div id="topColor"> </div>
  <br>
  <div id="navigation"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Why not use `background-color` instead? Does it really need to be `position:absolute`?

Comment: Oh my god, I have been writing so much javascript I didn't realize I used = instead of : 
thank you so much

Comment: How in the F is this considered off topic? is this not a code question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply an error in css syntax, `z-index = -1;` should be `z-index: -1;`

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

#topColor {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #9546c1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="headerWrapper">
    <h1><img class="centeredImage" src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="Logo"></h1>
  </div>
  <div id="navWrapper"> </div>
  <div id="topColor"> </div>
  <br>
  <div id="navigation"></div>
</body>
```

Although, you can also use `background-color` instead. Not really sure why you need to use `position:absolute` if it is only for background color. Just add `height: 100%;` to the `body` and `html`, and also for `#topColor`

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

#topColor {
  background-color: #9546c1;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="topColor">
    <div id="headerWrapper">
      <h1><img class="centeredImage" src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="Logo"></h1>
    </div>
    <div id="navWrapper"> </div>
    <br>
    <div id="navigation"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -2):

So guys, I figured out what was wrong, I just had spaced out and put an = operator instead of : next to my z-index in the CSS.

I was switching between Javascript and CSS too frequently. Sorry everyone for posting this, my bad